# template strategy pattern

Tags: c++, templates

I want to breakup a class so that its decoupled from the logic of performing certain task so that users can write new strategies as they wish to without interfering with the central model. So, I want to use templated strategy class but without having to have the user of the strategy to be templatised:

```
   class Model {  
     ...  
     boost::shared_ptr< Strategy < T > > m_pStrategy;  
     ...  
     public:  
     template <  typename T  >  
     void DoSomething() { m_pStrategy < T > ::DoSomething(); }  
    };
```

I would like the DoSomething function to not be templated. Is there any other way I can achieve what I want to do here?

thanks.

Comment: You are parametrizing a *data member* in `DoSomething`. How does it even compile? And where does `T` come from in `Strategy < T >`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me like what you want to implement is a [Policy-Based Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design).  I'm not sure what `Model` and `Strategy` do exactly, but it seems like `Model` is the root class, and `Strategy` is the Policy class, which users would want to provide in some cases to perform special handling.  It also seems like the only reason you keep a pointer to the `Strategy<T>` object around is so that you can call functions on it.

In this case, you can design your class like this:

```
template<class Strategy> 
class Model : public Strategy {  
 public:  
 void DoSomething() 
 { 
    // magic happens (we will fill this in shortly)
 };
};
```

You call methods on the `Strategy` class to do your magic.  By letting the users define their own `Strategy` class, you give them the opportunity to define their own "magic".  You need to apply rules on what method the `Strategy` class will provide at a minimum, so that you can call those methods in `Model`.

For example, suppose `Model` is actually some kind of resource manager, capable of being a simple smart pointer, or something else like a resource manager for a Windows Critical Section.  Let's rename `Model` to `auto_resource` and `Strategy` will become `release_policy` and will be responsible for releasing whatever resource was assigned to it.  In that case, you might have:

```
class pointer_release_policy
{
public:
  template<class Object> void release(Object* obj) { delete obj; }  
};

template<class Managed, class release_policy>
class auto_resource : public release_policy
{
public:
  // ... ctors etc defined here
  ~auto_resource()
  {
    release_policy::release(managed_);
  }
private:
  Managed managed_;
};
```

Which you could use for `std::string` pointers like this:

```
typedef auto_resource<std::string*, pointer_release_policy> string_ptr;
string_ptr my_str;
```

...and when `my_str` falls off the stack, the `release` method will automatically be called.

Later you want to add a new policy for releasing Windows mutex `HANDLE`s:

```
class handle_release_policy
{
public:
  template<class Handle> void release(Handle h)
  { 
    CloseHandle(h); // this is a WINAPI function that deallocates the specified resource
  };
};
```

You can use this thusly:

```
typedef auto_resource<HANDLE, handle_resource_policy> handle_resource;
//... allocate & use the mutex...
handle_resource mutex = CreateMutex(0, 0, 0);
```

Of course, in order to flesh all this out you need to add functionality for assigning, copying, releasing etc the resources.  Here is a complete working example that puts everything together.  I've provided 2 sets of policies, one for Windows `CRITICAL_SECTION`s, and another for `SOCKET`s:

```
class SimpleCopyPolicy
{
public:
    template<class Resource> Resource copy(const Resource& rhs) const { Resource ret = rhs; return ret; }
protected:
    ~SimpleCopyPolicy(){};
};

class CritsecReleasePolicy
{
public:
    template<class Handle> bool release(Handle& h)
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&h);
        return true;
    }
protected:
    ~CritsecReleasePolicy() {};
};

class CritsecLockPolicy  // CRITICAL_SECTION lock/unlock policies
{
public:
    template<class Handle> bool lock(Handle& h)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(const_cast<CRITICAL_SECTION*>(&h));
        return true;
    }
    template<class Handle> bool unlock(Handle& h) 
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&h);
        return true;
    }
};


class SocketReleasePolicy
{
public:
    template<class Handle> bool release(Handle h) { return 0 != closesocket(h); }
protected:
    ~SocketReleasePolicy(){};
};

template<class Resource, typename ReleasePolicy, typename CopyPolicy = SimpleCopyPolicy>
class simple_auto_resource : public ReleasePolicy, public CopyPolicy
{
public:
    typedef simple_auto_resource<Resource,ReleasePolicy,CopyPolicy> base_type;

    simple_auto_resource() : res(0) {}
    simple_auto_resource(const Resource & r) : res(copy(r)) {}
    ~simple_auto_resource() { if(res) release(res); }

    void clear() { if(res) release(res); res = 0; }

    Resource& get() { return res; }
    const Resource& get() const { return res; }

    Resource detach() { Resource ret = res; res = 0; return ret; }

    operator const Resource&() const { return get(); }
    operator Resource&() { return get(); }

    base_type& operator=(const Resource& rhs) { clear(); res = copy(rhs); return * this; }

    template<class Comp> bool operator==(const Comp& rhs) const { return res == (Resource)rhs; }
    template<class Comp> bool operator!=(const Comp& rhs) const { return res != (Resource)rhs; }
    template<class Comp> bool operator<(const Comp& rhs) const { return res < (Resource)rhs; }
private:
    Resource res;
};

typedef simple_auto_resource<CRITICAL_SECTION, CritsecReleasePolicy> auto_critsec;
typedef simple_auto_resource<SOCKET,SocketReleasePolicy> auto_socket;
```

For more on policy-based design, see [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315).

...

Comment: its been over 2 years.. but this is good stuff. Let me ask you this. How does the _strategy pattern_  differ from _policy based pattern_ ? One thing I see from your code is a theme of varying contexts, with very similar strategy algorithms. the socket, pointer and HANDLE release policies all work on different contexts: _sockets pointers and Handles_ . The **design pattern** i am looking for is when the context is constant, but the algorithm/protocal is unique. So maybe there are two distink needs the many context for the **policy pattern** and the many protocals for the **strategy pattern**

Comment: maybe I will go into my design issues in a new _thread/question_ ... but im having a very hard time implementing the strategy pattern using **Modern C++ Design** techniques.. like your code above. I do not want to use any virtual functions, but without getting into Boost::MPI type stuff, im having a hard time designing my strategy pattern. any sugestions? ty @Grunch

Answer (score 0):

Move the function out of `class Strategy<T>`.